# how to redirect a dynamic url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a URL `www.example.com/page/abcderf`

=> `abcderf` <= is dynamic, it is never the same value.

I would like to redirect with `.htacess` from :

```
www.example.com/page/abcderf
```

to

```
www.example.com/page/
```

How to do ?

My attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\page\.[a-zA-Z0-9])$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/page/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `/abcderf` / `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - Do you need to be specific with what comes after `/page/`? Or is it OK to match any URL that simply starts with `/page/`? Your example URL does not end with a slash, except that your `RewriteRule` specifically matches only URLs that do end with a slash?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any conditions, one single line should work:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /page/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

or as MrWhite mentioned if you don't need to know what was in the URL

```
RewriteRule ^page/. /page/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

NC = no case
L = Last (don't run anything after)
R=301 = 301 redirect

Comment: There's no second (or trailing) slash in the example URL in the question. This could perhaps be simplified to just `^page/.` (no need for the capturing subgroup).